# Apps not writing to SD Card

Tags: external-sd

I use a Motorola X4, Android 9. I have been storing app data on my SD card for over 2 years. Several months ago, this capability vanished, and I started getting storage full warnings from Files. The particular apps are Merlin and Oruxmaps. I have tried reformatting the SD card and also tried changing write permissions. Neither worked.

What must I do to restore this capability?